# Keep current value when edit in datagrid - Adobe Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have two datagrids, and it's possible to drag any items from datagrid A to drop in datagrid B. In datagrid B, I can edit the values, and those values have limits minimum and maximum. The values have a currency format. However, I have a problem: when I edit a value in an item dropped in datagrib B, the value automatically change to minimum value.

The correct is keep the current value when edit.

Any idea?

The code:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               width="650"
               creationComplete="initApp();">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

        private function initApp():void {
            dgA.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection([
                {Expense:'Electricity', Value:300, minNo: 100, maxNo: 500},
                {Expense:'Phone', Value:200, minNo: 50, maxNo: 300},
                {Expense:'Contract A', Value:5000, minNo: 4000, maxNo: 6000},
                {Expense:'Contract B', Value:6000, minNo: 4500, maxNo: 8500},
                {Expense:'Contract C', Value:3000, minNo: 2500, maxNo: 3500}
            ]);

            dgB.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection([]);
        }

        private function disableEditing(event:DataGridEvent):void {
            if(event.columnIndex==0)
            {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }

        protected function LabelFormatter(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
        {
            return MoedaFormatter.format(item.Value);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:CurrencyFormatter id="MoedaFormatter" precision="2" currencySymbol="R$" alignSymbol="left" decimalSeparatorTo="," decimalSeparatorFrom=","  thousandsSeparatorFrom="." thousandsSeparatorTo="."/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:HGroup>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label text="Cost 1"/>
        <mx:DataGrid id="dgA"
                     allowMultipleSelection="true" 
                     dragEnabled="true" 
                     dropEnabled="true" 
                     dragMoveEnabled="true">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Expense"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Value" labelFunction="LabelFormatter"/>
            </mx:columns>    
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </s:VGroup>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label text="Cost 2"/>
        <mx:DataGrid id="dgB"
                     allowMultipleSelection="true" 
                     dragEnabled="true" 
                     dropEnabled="true" 
                     dragMoveEnabled="true"
                     editable="true"
                     itemEditBeginning="disableEditing(event);">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Expense"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Value" editorDataField="value" labelFunction="LabelFormatter">
                    <mx:itemEditor>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <mx:NumericStepper stepSize="1" width="35" height="20">
                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        override public function set data(value:Object):void
                                        {
                                            super.data = value;

                                            if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("minNo")) {
                                                minimum = value.minNo;
                                            }

                                            if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("maxNo")) {
                                                maximum = value.maxNo;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>
                            </mx:NumericStepper>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemEditor>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>    
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:HGroup>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the set data method in your itemeditor as below

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
     super.data = value;
     if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("Value")) {
        super.value = value.Value;
     }
     if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("minNo")) {
        minimum = value.minNo;
     }

     if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("maxNo")) {
        maximum = value.maxNo;
     }
}
```

I have tested this myself and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

When you drop items from dgA, you drop object that contains minNo and maxNo properties, and script, hooked to change of data property assigns minimum and maximum properties of the item renderer.

So, just remove  tag nested in dgB or comment it.

Comment: If I remove the tag, how do I define the limit values?

Comment: Do you need to have them defined? They are not defined at the start, only after you drop items from dgA.

Comment: I percept a thing: if I remove the labelFunction LabelFormatter in dgB, it's works! So, the problem is this label! Any idea?

Comment: Probably collision between labelFunction, that converts the data into some weird string and NumericStepper item renderer, that takes this string, fails to see it as a number and just resets to min value instead.

Comment: Didn't you just resolved it? Or you need it all? Min/max, and NumericStepper, and formatted string to display?

Comment: yes, I need all those elements. I need to define the limits for each value to edit in datagrid B. And I need the formatted string to display the currency.

Comment: I think to remove the labelFunction and create a function to format string when edit the value. But how do I make this? Any idea?

Comment: You can add "change" listeners to any user input elements. Probably you should tell what do you want to get in the end of all this. In general.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-79ce.html So you put change="yourHandler(event);" and in the handler function event.currentTarget is the reference to the component that fired that event.

Comment: You can go for more UX-complicated solution, like to show a NumericStepper floating over on user clicks the dgB cells, focus it, let user edit the value, and then update the value after user presses **enter** or on focus out of NumericStepper.

Comment: thank you for tips. I´m trying until now, but not success. =(